# Character formatting leaks into tag links

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, tag-links

[asdf](/questions/tagged/asdf)

*asdf [asdf](/questions/tagged/asdf) asdf*

**asdf [asdf](/questions/tagged/asdf) asdf**

***asdf [asdf](/questions/tagged/asdf) asdf***

You can also do <sup>[asdf](/questions/tagged/asdf)</sup>, but that's probably okay to leave alone. It's mainly just the character styles (bold, italic, etc.) that I think could use fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is that a bug? You said you wanted begin bold, tag, end bold -- and that's what you got.

Comment: Well yes, but aren't tags supposed to have consistent formatting? That was part of the point of adding the new syntax. And I don't see any bolded tags around the site anywhere...

Comment: @Jon look down: "Not the answer you're looking for? ..."

Comment: @radp: True....