# Allow [tag:tag-name] syntax to link to any site

Tags: feature-request, tags, markdown, hyperlinks

The tag [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) and meta-tag [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) syntax generate much nicer looking results than merely surrounding your tag with [square brackets].

However, they only work when you're talking about the site you're on.  On Area51, in Chat, and on Meta sites, this is frequently not the case, leading to attempts at syntax like `[[tag:failure]](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failure)`, which produces:

[[tag:failure]](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failure)

Hmm, must be some subtle syntax thing:

- [tag:failure](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failure): `[tag:failure](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failure)`
- [[tag:failure](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failure)]: `[[tag:failure](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failure)]`
- [failure](/questions/tagged/failure): `[tag:[failure]((https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failure))]`
- [[tag:failure]](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failure): `<a href="https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failure">[tag:failure]</a>`
- [tag:failure](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failure): `[tag:failure][1] \n\n [1]: https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failure`
- [more text is a [tag:failure] too](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failure): `[more text is a [tag:failure] too](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failure)`

I give up!

How can I create a link to a tag on another site with tag markdown?

Comment: Related: the [original request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69513/allow-specifying-sites-for-the-new-tag-formatting-at-least-to-some-degree) that let us specify Meta versus not. This is also more of a feature-request than a bug report - otherwise, it's very much bydesign that it's not possible to use tag syntax to specify sites other than the main and meta.

Comment: @Grace Note - Would you like to comment on (or provide as an answer) your statement in the linked original request? You wrote: *"I can see that being able to specify any SE site would be problematically annoying."*  I agree with the default behavior, but would like `[[tag:name]](url)` to override it.

Comment: Also related: [Character formatting leaks into tag links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71109/146495) - To extend Jeff's logic, I said I want to hyperlink, and that's not what I got - therefore, this is a bug.

Comment: I made that statement as the benefit vs. work ratio is quite skewed. Referring to tags on other sites is a very infrequent use-case, and must support a growing number of possible sites that become increasingly irrelevant to the starting site. Nevermind that it can probably be very clumsy to write. As such, it's problematic in comparison to sticking with what's familiar to that site, the far more prevalent use case. Altering the default behavior (which is what my proposal was) is a different beast from overriding the syntax as a whole with a markdown hyperlink.

Comment: @GraceNote is this feature-request scoped for the future? I think it would make much sense to have it, specially when in Meta talking about the tags in other sites.

Answer (score 8):

We should provide something like following:

- `[site-tag:tagname]` or `[site:tag:tagname]` for **another *main*** site
- `[site-meta-tag:tagname]` or `[site:meta-tag:tagname]` for **another *meta*** site.

Comment: This? `[so:tag:java]`? `[gaming:meta-tag:status-completed]`